# "../lib/libfreenect.so.0.5.0: undefined reference to `libusb_get_parent'" when building libusb

Tags: compiling

I am trying to install OpenKinect on Ubuntu. I get this error when I run

```
tesla@ubuntu:~/libusb/libfreenect/build$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for tesla: 


[ 51%] Built target freenectstatic
Linking C executable ../bin/freenect-chunkview
../lib/libfreenect.so.0.5.0: undefined reference to `libusb_get_parent'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/freenect-chunkview] Error 1
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/freenect-chunkview.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Yes, I have installed libusb and libusb-1.0-0-dev
I have a 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine (VMware player)

I even tried installing on Ubuntu 14.04, but with same error.
I have enabled USB 3.0 support too.

Answer (score -1):

you should try to build libusb from latest-source-tar from http://libusb.info/.
i had the same troubles with an old version of "libusb-1.0.0".

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work.